# How to best treat the output from a child component as a stream

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming, angular-components

In my app I have a component that would prefer to think of the output of a child component as a stream, rather than handling it with an event handler. In other words, something like

Template:

```html
<child-component (output)="onOutput($event)"></child-component>
```

Component:

```js
output$: Subject<any>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.output$
    .pipe(preprocessFilterAndMapPipe)
    .subscribe(output => console.log("got output", output));
}

onOutput(output) { this.output$.next(output); }
```

if you see what I mean. I wonder if there is any more streamlined way of writing this.

One idea would be to pass the subject to the child component and have that child component `next` its emissions onto that subject, instead of outputting in the normal, EventEmitter-based way, as in:

Child component:

```js
@Input() output$: Subject<any>;

onSomeEvent() { this.output$.next(someData); }
```

but this seems to vaguely violate the expected semantics of `@Input` and `@Output`.

I could write the following, which saves me the trouble of writing an event handler just to place the event on my observable, but it seems ugly:

```html
<child-component (output)="output$.next($event)"></child-component>
```

Are there any known patterns for doing this? Could decorators help?

On another note, is there any way to know from a parent component that an output from a child component has "terminated"? In other words, when `eventEmitter.complete()` was called?

Comment: you can create separate service for child to parent communication

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the components that are involved in the communication. If your data has to be passed up the hierarchy `(parent->grand-parent)`, then `@Output()` will do the job. If it has to be for some other component, then you have to implement `publish/subscribe` concept using `rxjs/Subject` inside the shared `Service`.

Comment: Thanks for your "input". This is not a generic question about inter-component communication. It is specifically about the easiest way to treat a sequence of outputs from a child component directly as a stream (rxjs Observable) in the parent.

Comment: Again it completely depends on the number of components you have and where exactly you want to utilize the child data(means which level of parent actually wants it). For two or three components in the hierarchy @Output() is fine. More than that you will see your code starts getting ugly with unnecessary @Output() events. In that case it is best to use shared service and only subscribe in the parent components that rely on that data.

Comment: `Output` is kinda imperative from the parent component's viewpoint. To use Output, you have to create a callback to handle it -- or call an explicit `mySubject.next` in the template, which is even worse. OP asked for a less imperative, more reactive (streamy) approach.

Answer (score 0):

Obtain a reference to the child component in the parent component using `@ViewChild` then subscribe a subject belonging to the parent component (in this case `output$`) to the subject belonging to the child component (in this case also called `output$`).

```
  @ViewChild(ChildComponent) childComponent: ChildComponent;

  output$ = new Subject();

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.childComponent.output$.subscribe(this.output$);
  }
```

Comment: I have no doubt that would work, but don't see too much different between that and just having a shared `output$` at the top of some random global module, which is a programming style my Mom told me to avoid.

Comment: What is the difference then for what you are looking for?

Comment: It technically works, but this way you'd couple the template (HTML) and the logic (TS) a little stronger than ideal. This way the logic (TS) would expect a `ChildComponent` in the template. Ideally the logic has to know nothing about the contents of the template.